# Go offline and reconnect with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, offline

Is there a way I can go offline and reconnect with javascript / jquery. I am hoping to do this in hopes of establishing a better connection, hopefully.

The only way I can think of doing this is triggering the offline event with jQuery's `.trigger('offline');` and then somehow reconnecting.

Is there a better way to do this? And / Or a way I can establish a stronger connection?

Comment: You want your code to take your device offline, then reconnect it?  JavaScript has no means of controlling your network or Internet connection.  It's up to the user and their device to manage "connections".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of environment are you developing in? Since you're using jQuery, I assume you are in a browser. If that is the case, then no, you cannot affect the computer's network connection with JavaScript. Think of how awful that would be if every website you visited could hijack control of your internet connection!

Comment: That is very true. Then why is there an offline event then?

Comment: so you can tell when your network connection has gone offline? Useful if your requesting information from a server. Think Facebook chat, telling you your connection is down.